# Perl read line string without trailing newline

Tags: perl, variables

Very new to perl and have been stuck for quite awhile on this.

If I change the variable from READSTDIN to google.com, it says google.com is online as it should. If I use the STDIN and input google.com and print $host it prints google.com, however in the ping it doesn't work.

Sample output:

```
    perl perl.pl
What is the website that is offline or displaying an error?google.com
Warning: google.com
 appears to be down or icmp packets are blocked by their server
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Ping;

#optionally specify a timeout in seconds (Defaults to 5 if not set)
my $timeout = 10;

# Create a new ping object
my $p = Net::Ping->new("icmp");

#Domain variable
print "What is the website that is offline or displaying an error?";
my $host = readline STDIN;

# perform the ping
if ( $p->ping( $host, $timeout ) ) {
    print "Host $host is alive\n";
} else {
    print "Warning: $host appears to be down or icmp packets are blocked by their server\n";
}

# close our ping handle
$p->close();
```

If I change the variable from READSTDIN to google.com, it says google.com is online as it should. If I use the STDIN and input google.com and print $host it prints google.com, however in the ping it doesn't work. I appreciate anyone who can help me at all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm looking for some clarification on chomp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290445/im-looking-for-some-clarification-on-chomp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my file content/user input not match? (missing chomp canonical)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571878/why-does-my-file-content-user-input-not-match-missing-chomp-canonical)

Answer (score 1):

Note the newline in your input:

```
    perl perl.pl
What is the website that is offline or displaying an error?google.com
Warning: google.com <--- newline after google.com puts the rest of the output on the next line...
 appears to be down or icmp packets are blocked by their server
```

You should be using [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) to remove the newline from your input:

```
chomp( my $host = readline STDIN );
```

Or more simply:

```
chomp( my $host = <STDIN> );  # same thing as above
```

Comment: I'm not bothered by the new line being outputted (but thanks for helping me there) -- I'm more concerned that it doesn't recognize that my variable READLINE STDIN "google.com" is online. If I change the variable from
    my $host = readline STDIN;
to
my $host = "google.com"

The script correctly outputs that google.com is online, if however I input google.com when it asks me
"What is the website that is offline or displaying an error?"
It tells me google.com is offline.

Comment: No. It's telling you that "google.com\n" is offline. Which it is. There's no tld 'com\n' so the name fails to resolve.

Comment: Because you are not chomping the input, your program is telling you that "google.com\n" is off line.  Your input buffer $line, includes the newline, because that is how buffered input on ttys works.  Since there is no server with a newline in its name, you can't ping it.  The when you go to print it, the newline in the buffer causes the newline in the output.

Comment: Thanks so much! Apologies I misunderstood, that totally makes sense.
What is the website that is offline or displaying an error?google.com
Host google.com is alive
:)